# How to union two polygon shapefiles by one or more attribute fields in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, merge, attribute-joins, union

I would like to union two polygons that have the exact same fields in their attribute tables in QGIS. However when I use the Union tool, it makes an attribute table that has exactly twice the amount of fields, and the new fields are named "X_2", "Y_2", "Z_2", etc.

Is there a way when joining the polygons to just insert one polygon's records into the existing fields of the other? I want to add new rows, I do not want to insert or replace one shapefile's records with those of the other

Shapefile 1 is the top half of the country, Shapefile 2 is the bottom half of the country,

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing with the shapes.  You might add some visuals.   Are you dealing with multiple polygons in one layer or multiples across two or more layers?  Are you creating multiparts from singleparts (as in a merger of spatially separated polygons) or dissolving touching/overlapping polygons?  A table join based on some spatial relationship or attribute value is another option.

Comment: I've added a visual. I'm dealing with multiple polygons within 2 separate layers. I don't want to merge any polygon parts, I just want to put all the records of one layer's field as new records in the second layer's field

Comment: Select All Features (from one layer), Copy Features (Ctrl-C), switch to other layer, Paste Features (Ctrl-V). Or is your data more complex than that?

Comment: How do I copy and paste within an attribute table so that it creates new records of all the copied records in the second table?

Comment: Use the merge vector layers tool.

Comment: I get the following error when trying that: Feature could not be written to Merged_9dfb31f6_efa4_4d69_9baf_a5809d1512c7: Could not store attribute "Map code": String of length 44 exceeds maximum field length (40)
Could not write feature into OUTPUT

Comment: I suspect the map code field in one layer allows larger text width than that in the other layer.  I don't see a simple way in the tool form to set a width for the merged result.  So if one layer is indeed different  you could try Tom's suggestion to select and copy all the shapes in the layer with the shorter width field and paste them into the other.  Of if you want a new layer you could use the refactor tool to change the width of the shorter field to match the wider one, and then merge those to a new layer.

Comment: The copy-paste option seems to be what I want but I don't know the workflow for how to do it

Comment: Select all the records in a layer and then while that layer is still active choose Edit - Copy.  Then activate the other layer, start editing it and use Edit - Paste.

Comment: This worked, thank you very much. If you post that as an answer I will check mark it as the solution.

Does this only work for single field copy-pastes, or can it copy all fields for each record? And what happens if the two shapefiles have different fields? Will it know to match the fields that have the same name?

Comment: It copies all fields from the source layer. Fields with the *exact* same name will be matched, source fields that do not have a match in the target layer will be discarded on paste.

Comment: Are you trying to use the "UNION" tool (that creates separate features for overlapping and non-overlapping parts) or are you  trying to use the "Merge Vector Layers" tool (that combines multiple vector layers of the same geometry type into a single one) ?

Comment: I've tried both. Union doesn't do what I want, and merge vector layers can't complete because of an error in the string length of a field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your two layers presumably have the same attributes, you can just copy and paste:

- Edit -> Select -> Select All Features
- Edit -> Copy Features (Ctrl-C on Windows)
- Switch to other layer
- Layer -> Toggle Editing (if layer is not already in Edit mode - otherwise the Paste Features option will be greyed out)
- Edit -> Paste Features (Ctrl-V)

If you are merging layers with different attributes, only the attributes that match the layer that you are pasting into will be pasted.

[The features will still be pasted though]

Answer (score 2):

You can use SQL with [UNION](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) operator. If you can have duplicate records, you should use UNION ALL, or the duplicates are dropped.

```SQL
SELECT * FROM "LayerA"
UNION
SELECT * from "LayerB"
```

All features from layer a with all fields (*), combined with the same from field b.

Then load the result to the, right-click and export to file.

[image]